# Select input from in memory html in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to run jQuery selector on an in memory representation of some html.

If I have:

```
var html = $('<input id="testBox" type="text" value="test" />');
var result = $('#testBox', html);
console.log(result.val());
```

I will get back `undefined` as result will hold a `prevObject`

How can I return the actual input directly from the selector here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `html` is the jQuery wrapped `<input />`. For example:

```
console.log( html.attr('id'); ); // testBox
```

Your code would work if you wrapped the input in some other tag, for example:

```
var html = $('<div><input id="testBox" type="text" value="test" /></div>');
var result = $('#testBox', html);
console.log(result.val()); // test
```

Comment: thanks.  This does work but only with a div tag - not a body tag.  why is this?

Comment: It doesn't work with the body wrapper because jQuery removes body, html and head special tags, so if you use body as a wrapper then `html` is the input element, just like your original code (with no wrapper) and you can do `html.attr('id'); // testBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to run a selector; `html` is the actual input:

```
console.log(html.val());
```